# $.ajax call fail with dataType is json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I would like to send an ajax call to a JSON file to retrieve the data. But ajax call failed with `dataType: "json"`. When i change dataType to `"text"`, ajax call successfully.

below is the code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        console.log("success");
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("failed");
    }
});
```

the JSON file is:

```
{
 "mobile": [{"中国": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]},
            {"美国": ["3", "5", "10", "20", "30", "50"]}
           ],
 "uni": [{"德国": ["5", "10", "20", "30", "50"]},
         {"英国": ["30", "50", "00", "20", "50"]}
        ],
 "telcom": [{"法国": ["10", "20", "30", "50", "00", "500"]}
           ]
}
```

Comment: is there any error in the browser console...

Comment: try the error handle as `error: function (jqXhr, status, error) {
        alert(status + ':' + error + ':' + jqXhr.responseText)
    }
`

Comment: make sure you are returning json response (text/json) from your server. Your data is json but the response type must also be json.

Comment: @ Arun P Johny Hi, it shows parsererror:SyntaxError: Unexpected token. i think the problem is there are some chinese characters in this json file, i just paste part of the json file in this question.

Comment: I found the problem is caused by the Chinese character in this json file. how to do the ajax call when json file contains Chinese characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON you've provided is a valid one, so I think the error is in other place.
You can use the [multiple values](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) space-separated into `dataType` setting, like this:

```
dataType: "text json",
```

So jquery will get the result as text and after that interpret it as JSON.

In comments you're saying that there are some chinese characters, try to encode them in Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the data type is not JSON, but rather `application/json`. Try

```
    dataType: "application/json"
```

but if that doesn't work, you can always use a dataType of text, and `JSON.parse` it afterwards, as that's all JSON is anyway.